# How to check productid from two different database (compare two lists and return not matching items to add)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I have two databases, one is main and another is for add to cart.

I want to check add to cart prodid with main database prodid.

```
// here I get an error "data type issue" - that's why I convert to int
var db1prodid = Convert.ToInt32(db1.prod.Select(x => x.prodid).ToList());  

var gg = Convert.ToInt32(db2.prod.Select(x => x.prodid).ToList().ToString());
var checkprodid = db2.prod.Where(x => gg == db1prodid ).ToList();
```

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(db1.prod.Select(x => x.prodid).ToList())`? How this is working? You are trying to convert `List` to a `int`?

Comment: actually, if you want to convert, change your code as below: `var db1prodid = db1.prod.Select(x =>(int)x.prodid).ToList();` or `var db1prodid = db1.prod.Select(x =>Convert.ToInt32(x.prodid)).ToList();`

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Select prods from db2 which id exists in db1?

Comment: @mj1313 yes, I want to compare with these both id's in both databse, but these database's isn't in relation

Comment: The answer posted by @hesamakbari should work.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert,
change your code as shown below:

```
var db1prodid = db1.prod.Select(x =>(int)x.prodid).ToList();
```

//or

```
var db1prodid = db1.prod.Select(x =>Convert.ToInt32(x.prodid)).ToList();
```

anyway, to compare two lists and return not matching items, you can do as below

```
var db1prodid = db1.prod.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.prodid)).ToList();

var checkprodid = db2.prod.Where(x => !db1prodid.Contains(x.prodid)).ToList();
```

it'll return all rows in `db2.prod` that does not exist in `db1.prod`

At the same way,

```
var db2prodid = db2.prod.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.prodid)).ToList();

var checkprodid = db1.prod.Where(x => !db1prodid.Contains(x.prodid)).ToList();
```

it'll return all rows in `db1.prod` that does not exist in `db2.prod`